# When scraping websites I get the error "Took longer than 180.0 seconds". Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

While I run the script, the scrapy is continuously throwing this message:

```
Took longer than 180.0 seconds
```

What are the causes for this problem and any specific solution for this?

Here is the screenshot of this message.
[image]

Comment: Why this question is taking negative votes?

Comment: we are not imgur, we do not care about images of Code, Exceptions or Stacktraces - we need text to copy&paste  - also: your imagelink might get stale, if you copy&paste the text into your question it will live as long as your question. (dicslaimer, not my dv)

Answer (score 6):

You are hitting the scrapy timeout when downloading.

See  **[DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-timeout)**

It defaults to 360 seconds = 6 minutes. Adjust your setting to make it longer.

According to the documentation your Settings

> can be populated using different mechanisms, each of which having a different precedence. Here is the list of them in decreasing order of precedence:
>
> Command line options (most precedence)
>   Settings per-spider
>   Project settings module
>   Default settings per-command
>   Default global settings (less precedence)

You did not share your code, so its difficult to tell, but either you modify the settings for your spider or provide them as commandline option.

> ```
> scrapy crawl myspider -s DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT=<some value that benefits you crawling>
> ```

Alternativly you can set them per-spider like so:

> ```
> class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
>     name = 'myspider'
>
>     custom_settings = {
>         'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 'some value',
>     }
> ```

For more information read [the settings-manual](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for this guidance. I've underline the mistakes.